# The Service "traefik-ingress-service" is invalid when try to run traefik-deeployment.yml

Tags: yaml

I am trying to deploy traefik as ingress controller in microk8s. When I create the file through: microk8s.kubectl -f traefik-deployment.yml

I get the error: The Service "traefik-ingress-service" is invalid:

I tried to search on internet but couldn't find any relevent help.

This is my traefik-deployment file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1 
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: traefik-ingress-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: traefik-ingress-controller
        name: traefik-ingress-controller
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: traefik
        name: traefik-ingress-controller
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        - name: webui
          containerPort: 8080
        args:
        - --api
        - --kubernetes
        - --logLevel=INFO
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-controller
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: tcp
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: tcp
    - name: webui
      port: 8080
      protocol: tcp

  type: NodePort
```

the output i get is:

```
serviceaccount/traefik-ingress-controller created
deployment.apps/traefik-ingress-controller created
The Service "traefik-ingress-service" is invalid: 
* spec.ports[0].protocol: Unsupported value: "tcp": supported values: "SCTP", "TCP", "UDP"
* spec.ports[1].protocol: Unsupported value: "tcp": supported values: "SCTP", "TCP", "UDP"
* spec.ports[2].protocol: Unsupported value: "tcp": supported values: "SCTP", "TCP", "UDP"
```

It seems it has created the service but when I see it from:

```
sudo microk8s.kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

I see the container in error state.

Answer (score 0):

It is just saying to write "TCP" with capital letters, instead of small letters.

But the error with the container has nothing to do with this. This is just a service to expose the deployment.